# request.getParameter returns null in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have the following code and the problem is that out.println("Clave= " +request.getParameter("clave")+"."); writes null. 
I have been searching a solution in this forum but I can't find anything.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Registro de votante</title>
        <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="CreaVotante">
        <div id="reg">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <h1>Reg&iacute;strate para votar</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <p>NIF</p> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="nif">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>Clave</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="clave">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="registro">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
package Controlador;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Lux
 */
public class CreaVotante extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet CreaVotante</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Nif= " +request.getParameter("nif")+ "</h1>");
            out.println("<h1>Clave= " +request.getParameter("clave")+ "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks ok. Do you have any filter, which could interfere?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to see what parameters are actually being sent with the form post.  May also be available via your IDE if you're using one.  Then at least you can see if the clive parameter isn't sent, it's the HTML, if it is being sent, it's your servlet code.

Comment: It start working once I restart NetBeans.